# R: summarise n and number of 1s by group

Tags: r

I have a dataset in the following format:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(420)
data <- data.frame(duration = c(3, 5, 6, 8, 10),
                   rate = c(0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9)) %>%
  slice_sample(n = 705, replace = TRUE) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(cured = sample(0:1, 1, prob = c(1 - rate, rate))) %>%
  select(-rate)
head(data)

  duration cured
     <dbl> <int>
1       10     1
2       10     1
3        5     1
4        3     1
5       10     0
6       10     1
```

And I wish to summarise the number of 1s and total number by `duration` (note this is a numeric not a factor, but will always be integers). I can do it by:

```
data %>%
  group_by(duration) %>%
  summarise(n = n(),
            npos = sum(cured, na.rm = TRUE),
            rate = npos / n)

  duration     n  npos  rate
     <dbl> <int> <int> <dbl>
1        3   139    30 0.216
2        5   130    79 0.608
3        6   143   123 0.860
4        8   155   127 0.819
5       10   138   118 0.855
```

This works fine, but I have a situation where the column names `duration` and `cured` are not necessarily called that, so I would like to pass it in as a variable instead. I would also like to remove the tidyverse dependency (this will eventually be in a package). Additionally, if there is missing data in `cured`, can it be completely ignored from both the `n` and `npos` columns in the summary.

Finally, I am using `pull(rate)` to get the `rate` column as a vector - is there a base R equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

We could use `aggregate`, and extract with `[[`, e.g. like this:

```
fun <- function(data, x, y) {

aggregate(data[x],
          by = data[y],
          FUN = \(x) sum(x, na.rm = FALSE) / length(na.omit(x)))[[x]]

}

fun(data, "cured", "duration")
```

Output:

```
[1] 0.2158273 0.6076923 0.8601399 0.8193548 0.8550725
```

Comment: This is perfect thanks! One question, if I want to generate more than one summary statistic in the same call, how can I do that? I have tried using c(stat1, stat2) in the function call but the result is 5x2 dataframe, but somehow still has all the information. What is going on there?

Comment: :) Try: `FUN = \(x) c(stat1(x), stat2(x))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach using `mean`:

1. We `aggregate` column `x` by `y`.
2. then we apply `mean` to calculate the average in each group.
3. Finally we extract the second column.

```
fun <- function(data, x, y) {
  aggregate(data[,x], list(data[,y]), \(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))[ , 2]
}

fun(data, "cured", "duration")
```

```
[1] 0.2158273 0.6076923 0.8601399 0.8193548 0.8550725
```